# How do I find common items from Python dictionary values?

Tags: python, set

Say, I have a dictionary `D`:

```
D = {'A': {1, 2, 3}, 'B': {2, 4, 5}, 'C': {1, 2, 7}}
```

Now I want to have all common items from `D`'s values, which would be 2.
I tried to use `set.intersection` but it did not work out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply, use [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set.intersection) method of `set`:

```
>>> set.intersection(*D.values())
{2}
```

`D.values()` will return a list of your dictionary values which are already sets, then `*D.values()` will unpack this list and pass it to `intersection` method of `set` class

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of variety, you could also use `reduce()`:

```
>>> D = {'A': {1, 2, 3}, 'B': {2 ,4, 5}, 'C': {1, 2, 7}}
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, D.values())  # or use operator.and_ instead of lambda
{2}
```

[`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) is a built-in function in Python 2.x, but needs to be imported from the [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html) module in Python 3.x.

Comment: Is `reduce` available in Python3+ ?

Comment: @Iron Fist: in Python 3.x you need to say `from functools import reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for common values in each dictionary and not looking for a value that is in each dict then the following code will work! Not saying that this is the fastest or the best approach, but it works!
Returns a list of all duplicate values across the embedded dicts!

```
def findCommon(data):

    flipped = {}
    out = []

    for i in data:
        for value in data[i]:
            if value not in flipped:
                flipped[value] = [i]
            else:
                flipped[value].append(i)
    for i in flipped:
        if len(flipped[i]) > 1:
            out.append(i)
    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go with `reduce` the most efficient way is to use `operator.and_`

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_

D = {'A': {1, 2, 3}, 'B': {2, 4, 5}, 'C': {1, 2, 7}}

print(reduce(and_, D.values()))
```

But `set.intersection` will be hard to beat:

```
In [89]: from functools import reduce

In [90]: from operator import and_

In [91]: timeit reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, D.values())
1000 loops, best of 3: 221 µs per loop

In [92]: timeit reduce(and_,D. values())
10000 loops, best of 3: 170 µs per loop

In [93]: timeit set.intersection(*D.values())
10000 loops, best of 3: 155 µs per loop
```